# Python: How to speed up creating of objects?

Tags: python, optimization, python-2.7, iteration

I'm creating objects derived from a rather large txt file. My code is working properly but takes a long time to run. This is because the elements I'm looking for in the first place are not ordered and not (necessarily) unique. For example I am looking for a digit-code that might be used twice in the file but could be in the first and the last row. My idea was to check how often a certain code is used...

```
counter=collections.Counter([l[3] for l in self.body])
```

...and then loop through the counter. Advance: if a code is only used once you don't have to iterate over the whole file. However You are stuck with a lot of iterations which makes the process really slow.

So my question really is: **how can I improve my code?** Another idea of course is to oder the data first. But that could take quite long as well.

The crucial part is this method:

```
def get_pc(self):
    counter=collections.Counter([l[3] for l in self.body])
    # This returns something like this {'187':'2', '199':'1',...}

    pcode = []

    #loop through entries of counter
    for k,v in counter.iteritems():
        i = 0
        #find post code in body
        for l in self.body:
            if i == v:
                break
            # find fist appearence of key 
            if l[3] == k:
                #first encounter...
                if i == 0:
                    #...so create object
                    self.pc = CodeCana(k,l[2])
                    pcode.append(self.pc)
                i += 1
                # make attributes
                self.pc.attr((l[0],l[1]),l[4])
            if v <= 1:
                break
    return pcode
```

I hope the code explains the problem sufficiently. If not, let me know and I will expand the provided information.

Comment: For starters: use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension. You do not *need* the intermediary list. `Counter(l[3] for l in self.body)` is enough.

Comment: Why set `self.pc` in the loop? It'll be replaced by the next `CodeCana` object soon enough. Why wouldn't a local do here?

Comment: What does the data look like?

Comment: There is some rudimentary information in the file. So a single object is supposed to have the code and name once, but other data should be added to a list. And I want the list of object to be return so I can do something like `pco = mp.get_pc()` `pco[0].nodes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping over `body` way too many times. Collapse this into *one* loop, and track the `CodeCana` items in a dictionary instead:

```
def get_pc(self):
    pcs = dict()    
    pcode = []

    for l in self.body:
        pc = pcs.get(l[3])
        if pc is None:
            pc = pcs[l[3]] = CodeCana(l[3], l[2])
            pcode.append(pc)
         pc.attr((l[0],l[1]),l[4])

    return pcode
```

Counting all items first then trying to limit looping over `body` by that many times while still looping over all the *different* types of items defeats the purpose somewhat...

You may want to consider giving the various indices in `l` names. You can use tuple unpacking:

```
for foo, bar, baz, egg, ham in self.body:
    pc = pcs.get(egg)
    if pc is None:
        pc = pcs[egg] = CodeCana(egg, baz)
        pcode.append(pc)
     pc.attr((foo, bar), ham)
```

but building `body` out of [a `namedtuple`-based class](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields) would help in code documentation and debugging even more.

Comment: It does. Got somewhat stuck. Thanks for thinking along.